# Confusion regarding Lemma 5.10 in Lee's Riemannian Manifolds

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I am trying to learn about the exponential map $\mathrm{exp}$ and read about it in Lee's book Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction to Curvature. The Lemma I am confused about can be found on page $76$. It wants to show that for any $p \in M$ there exists an open neighbourhood $V$ of $0$ in $T_pM$ and $U$ of $p$ in $M$ such that $\mathrm{exp}_p:V \to U$ is a diffeomorphism. The proof goes as follows.

First identify $T_pM \cong T_0(T_pM)$ and compute $\mathrm{exp}_p(V)$ for a tangent vector $V \in T_pM$. Show that this is equal to $V$ under this identification and use the inverse function theorem.

So as far as I can see it, one first has to note that in general $\mathrm{exp}_p$ is only defined on $$\{v \in T_pM \ | \ c_v \ \text{is defined on an interval containing} \ [0,1]\},$$ where $c_v$ denotes the geodesic with $\dot{c}_v(0)=v.$ However, one wants to compute the composition $$T_pM \to T_0(T_pM) \to T_pM$$ where the first map is given by the identification and the second map is given by $d(\mathrm{exp}_p)_p.$ Now, since $\mathrm{exp}_p$ is differentiable one can define the differential of that map, but why is it defined on $T_0(T_pM)$ even though $\mathrm{exp}_p$ is not defined on the entire tangent space $T_pM$? Furthermore, I fear that this is rather trivial, but what exactly is the identification map $T_pM \cong T_0(T_pM)$? And why does $$(\mathrm{exp}_p)_*V=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right\vert_{t=0}(\mathrm{exp}_p \circ \tau)(t)$$ hold, where $(\mathrm{exp}_p)_*$ is defined as the composition of the exponential map with the identification above and $\tau(t)=tV.$ Is $V$ viewed as a derivation or a geometric tangent vector here? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: They are more general statement: first, $\exp_p$ is differentiable at $0\in T_pM$ so that its linear tangent map at $0$ is a linear map from $T_0(T_pM)$ to $T_{\exp_p(0)}M$. Second, for a generic vector space, the tangent map at any point is canonically isomorphic to $V$ itself (use the velocity-definition of the tangent space to see this). Last, this is the chain rule applied to the map $\exp_p\circ \tau$ at $t=0$: its evaluation is given by $(d_{\tau(0)}\exp_p) \tau'(0)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1: Domain of exp and identification map $T_pM \simeq T_0T_pM$

Even though $\exp_p$ is not entirely defined on $T_pM$, it is defined on an open neighbourhood of $0$ in $T_pM$, and that is all you need to calculate differential of maps between manifolds. It might be a little bit harder to prove that this domain of definition of $\exp_p$ is open in $T_pM$, but I will assume this is done in the book.

The identification map $f:T_pM\simeq T_0(T_pM)$ goes as follows: identify each $V\in T_pM$ with the derivative of a curve through $V$ given by
$$
(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\ni t\mapsto \tau_V(t):=tV
$$

Then, the identification is explicitly written as

$$
f(V) := \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\left( \tau_V(t)\right)=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\left( tV\right)
$$
where the right-hand side is a vector in $T_0(T_pM)$, since it is the derivative $\tau_V'(0)$ of a curve passing thru $0=\tau_V(0)\in T_pM$.

It is easy to prove$^\dagger$ that this identification is a linear isomorphism of vector spaces. The smallness of $t$ will be required so as not to exit the open nbd on which $\exp_p$ is defined.

Note this argument can be extended to show that for *any manifold* $N$ which happens to be a finite dimensional vector space (with natural topology $\simeq \mathbb{R}^N$) the tangent space at any point $x\in N$ is naturally isomorphic to the space itself $T_xN \simeq N$.

### 2: Yoga with exponential map

The result will follow from the following two results.

**Lemma**: let $\gamma_V:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\rightarrow M$ be a geodesic satisfying $\gamma_V(0)=p\in M$ and $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} \gamma_V(t) = V\in T_pM$.

Then, the curve $\beta_t(s):=\gamma_V(ts)$ is a geodesic satisfying $\beta(0)=p$ and $\frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0}\beta_t(s)=tV$.

*Proof*: we have that $\frac{d\beta_t}{ds} = t\frac{d\gamma_V}{dt}(ts)$. Then, the covariant derivative thru the curve $\beta_t$ of the field $\frac{d\beta_t}{ds}$ is via chain-rule:
$$
\frac{D}{ds}\frac{d\beta_t}{ds} = \frac{D}{ds}\left(
t \frac{d\gamma_V}{dt}(ts)
\right) = t \frac{D}{ds}\left(\frac{d\gamma_V}{dt}(ts)\right)
= t \left(\frac{D}{dt} \frac{d\gamma_V}{dt}\right)|_{ts} \frac{d(ts)}{ds}
$$
and the lest term vanishes because $\gamma_V$ is a geodesic. Thus $\beta$ is a geodesic, and it is obvious it satisfies the above.

**Corollary**:
The exponential map satisfies:

$$
\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} \exp_p(tV) = V
$$

for all $V\in T_pM$ that are also in the open domain of $\exp_p$.

*Proof*: the exponential $\exp_p(tV)$ is defined as $\gamma_{tV}(1)$ where $\gamma_{tV}(s)$ is the unique geodesic (w.r.t. s) that has initial velocity $tV$ through $p$. By the above lemma, we know that $\gamma_V(ts)$ is also a geodesic through $p$ with initial velocity $t\cdot V$. But geodesics are unique, and thus $\gamma_{tV}(s)=\gamma_V(ts)$ for small enough $t$ ($t<1$ actually suffices). Evaluating at $s=1$ yields
$$\gamma_{tV}(1) = \gamma_V(t)$$
or
$$\exp_p(tV) = \gamma_V(t).$$
Differentiating at $t=0$ you get
$$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} \exp_p(tV) = V$$

### 3: Endgame

You want to show that
$$
T_pM \overset{f}{\rightarrow} T_0(T_pM)\overset{(\exp_p)_{*0}}{\rightarrow}T_pM
$$
is an isomorphism. From the Section 1 we know that for any $V\in T_pM$
$$
f(V) = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} (tV)
$$
therefore the composition with the differential at $0$ of the exponential $\exp_p$ gives
$$
(\exp_p)_{*0} \circ f (V) = (\exp_p)_{*0})\left[
\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} (tV)
\right]
= \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} \exp_p(tV) = V
$$
due to the corollary above and how the differential of a map acts on tangent vectors. Thus the composition coincides with the identity map $I_{T_pM}$ and it is an isomorphism. This implies that both $f$ and $(\exp_p)_{*0}$ are linear isomorphisms, and this, by the inverse function theorem, implies that $\exp_p$ is a local diffeomorphism from a nbd of $0$ in $T_pM$ to a nbd of $p$ in $M$.

**Comments**:

$^\dagger$: in order to show this is an isomorphism, you can take a coordinate chart $\{x^i\}$ around $p$, and use this to induce a basis of vectors $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\}$ of $T_pM$. This induces global coordinates $\tilde{x}^i$ (w.r.t. this basis) on $T_pM$ which in turn induces a basis of vectors on $T_0(T_pM)$. Prove that the identification map $f$ sends $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ to $\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^i}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Some things are not yet clear to me. I assume that derivative of the curve $\tau$ means to evaluate $d(\tau)_0(\frac{d}{dt}\vert_0)$, where the $\frac{d}{dt}$ denotes the coordinate basis vector of $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$.  This would then give an element in $T_0(T_pM)$ assuming that $\tau(t)=tV$ (do you mean this in your answer? You wrote $V+tV$). Applying $d(exp_p)$ would give $d(exp_p \circ \tau)(\frac{d}{dt}\vert_0)$ by the chain rule which is defined as $\frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t=0} exp_p(\tau(t))$ which would give the answer. Is this correct?

Comment: When knowing that the domain is open, does one use something like $T_pU \cong T_pM$ for any open subset $U$ of $M$? If so, does one then use the exponential map composed with this identification?

Comment: Yes! The inclusion of an open subset $i:U\rightarrow M$ induces an isomorphism between tangent spaces given by $i_{*p}:T_pU \rightarrow T_pM$.

Regarding your previous comment: I am implicitly using identification of tangent vectors to a manifold as derivatives of curves passing through the point in consideration. Note that the curve I propose is $\tau_V(t)=tV \in TpM$ for all $|t|<\varepsilon$. You are right I should have corrected this. Will edit answer.

Then, the identification $f:T_pM \rightarrow T_0(T_pM)$ is given by $f(V) := \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} \tau_V(t)$.

Comment: I see you are mixing notations with $d\exp_p$ and $(\exp_p)_*$ to denote the differential of the map $\exp_p: U(p)\subset M \rightarrow T_p M$, I just wanted to point this out: for me both of these denote the tangent map.

Comment: I have edited the answer substantially, following the proof given in O'Neils *Semi-Riemannian geometry and applications*, proving "the hard fact" of how the exponential map behaves when dilating the curve parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think it makes sense now. Especially using the chain rule in the last steps was not seen by me previously. Also pointing out further lemmas is helpful, so thanks for your effort! I can sadly only upvote once :P One final question, though. Does it matter whether $V$ is chosen as an algebraic tangent vector or a geometric? I prefer working with the algebraic ones as derivations and I don't think it makes a difference here, but maybe I am not seing something.

Comment: I am not really sure about the distinction between algebraic and geometric vectors. Possibly the firsts you mean "algebraic derivations on the space of smooth functions defined near the point" and the second is "tangent vectors to curves thru the point".

It does not matter, indeed: it is a standard result that these notions coincide! A tangent vector through a curve immediately gives you a derivation. The converse one is a little bit harder to prove, I suggest you check Lee's (Prop. 3.2 in Introduction to Smooth Manifolds).

Comment: Yes, those are the ones I mean, derivations and tangent vectors to curves through the point. I know that both spaces are isomorphic, but then the map is only well defined "up to isomorphism". However, in this case choosing $V$ to be either does not make a difference here I think, since it does not matter which tangent space we use here, meaning we need no additional composition.